# Submit a form without redirect

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have this form which I would like to submit and display a dialog window.

UI:

```HTML
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>test</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<main>
      
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="validationModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="validationModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="validationModalLabel">Confirmation</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Pair already exists for the same exchange.
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="col-md-10">
          <form id="add_pair_form" class="form-inline" action="#" th:action="@{/pairs}"
                th:object="${stepForm}"
                autocomplete="off"
                method="post">

            <div class="row g-3 align-items-center mb-1 mt-1">
              <div class="col-auto">
                  <label for="pair" class="form-label">New</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto">
                  <input id="pair" class="form-control" name="pair" type="text"
                          placeholder="Pair to be added."
                          th:field="*{validate_pairs}"
                          required
                          autofocus>
              ......................................
              </div>                            
            </div>

            <div class="form-group mb-1 mt-1">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit_btn">Submit</button>

              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#validationModal">
                Validate
              </button>
            </div>
              
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>       
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

API:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/validate_pairs")
    public void validatePair(Model model) {

        Response response = Response.builder().status(ResponseStatus.VALIDATION_ERROR).message("Some error message").build();
        
        model.addAttribute("response", response);
    }
```

How I can display the dialog window instead of redirecting the user to another page?

Answer (score 0):

when you submit a form if you want to prevent refresh page you should prevent of default event behavior event action like below:

```
$( "#add_pair_form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // add some needed functionality
});
```